# Vaadin JavaScript unload event listener not firing

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, vaadin7, onbeforeunload, onunload

I have a Vaadin 7 application where I need to reliably detect a user leaving or navigating away from a page in order to carry out some cleanup.

My aim is to have the page pop up a confirmation dialog on browser/tab close, and if the user chooses to leave the page, then at that point I perform the cleanup operation.

I am fairly inexperienced at JavaScript, but from what I have discovered 'onbeforeunload' and 'onunload' are the functions to use.

At this point in time, I am using the following code when I enter the page:

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(
    "beforeCloseListenerGlobal = function beforeCloseListener (e) {\nvar e = e || window.event;\nvar message = " + LEAVE_PAGE_MESSAGE + ";\nif(e) e.returnValue = message;\nreturn message;\n};\n" +
    "closeListenerGlobal = function closeListener () {\ncatchClose();\n};\n" +
    "addCloseListenersGlobal = function addCloseListeners () {\nwindow.addEventListener('beforeunload', beforeCloseListenerGlobal);\nwindow.addEventListener('unload', closeListenerGlobal);\n};\n" +
    "removeCloseListenersGlobal = function removeCloseListeners () {\nwindow.removeEventListener('beforeunload', beforeCloseListenerGlobal);\nwindow.removeEventListener('unload', closeListenerGlobal);\n};"       
);
```

Then, when I click the "Start" button on my interface to start the operation:

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("addCloseListenersGlobal();");
```

When I navigate away from my webpage, by closing the tab for example, I get a confirmation pop-up, just as I want. However, if I click Yes, the page closes but my 'unload' event does not fire. When I click the respective "Stop" button, the cleanup works correctly, so I know that part is fine.

From what I've read the major browsers all support onunload (I've tried Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera). More interestingly, if I use the following code, then my closeListener fires on the 'beforeunload' listener, but not on the 'unload' listener:

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(
    "function closeListener() { catchClose(); } " +
    "window.addEventListener('beforeunload', closeListener); " +
    "window.addEventListener('unload', closeListener);"
);
```

**So my question is, what could be the reason for the 'unload' listener not to fire?** Is this method a good and reliable way to perform a cleanup operation?

Note: below is my function callback for the cleanup operation on webpage close, in case that would have any effect on the 'unload' listener. I do not get a print out at all, so that implies the "catchClose" function is not called.

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().addFunction("catchClose", arguments -> {
    System.out.println("catchClose callback from " + Page.getCurrent().getWebBrowser().getBrowserApplication());
    presenter.webPageClosed();
});
```

Edit: Through further investigation it actually appears as though the unload method very occasionally does fire correctly, though I cannot pinpoint when and why it does that just yet. Also, I have discovered that if I put a breakpoint inside my "closeListener" function, it gets called, and my unload works absolutely fine.

Edit: For me it now appears as if the code works for Safari, Firefox and Opera, but not Chrome. I suspect it is due to a side effect from [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37704983/vaadin-javascript-popup-only-works-first-time-in-each-session) which I have now resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem.

I suspect that most of this issue was solved by the solution to [my other related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37704983/vaadin-javascript-popup-only-works-first-time-in-each-session) which involved putting certain parts of code into synchronous methods. After fixing this issue, the unload method worked across most of the browsers I have tested on. However, Chrome was still playing up and would only fire the unload event on browser close, and not on tab close. Adding in a 'pagehide' listener seems to mean that Chrome tab closing is now acting appropriately.

So, **a combination of 'unload' and 'pagehide' events seems to work across all browsers**, and (as of now for me) appears to be reliable, and my cleanup is always performed when the user leaves the page.